# cannot connect to wwan0 interface

Tags: networking, netplan

apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.
so i am trying to setup a network connection to my 4g modem using netplan like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
     wwx001e101f0000:
           dhcp4: true
```

but it doesnt seem to work what am i doing wrong :|

```
wwx001e101f0000: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 111 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=155e, bcdDevice= 1.02
usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-2: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
usb 2-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
option 2-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 2-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
option 2-2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 2-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
option 2-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 2-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
cdc_ncm 2-2:1.3: MAC-Address: 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
cdc_ncm 2-2:1.3: setting rx_max = 16384
cdc_ncm 2-2:1.3 wwan0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
cdc_ncm 2-2:1.3 wwx001e101f0000: renamed from wwan0
```

Comment: Try to change dhcp4: true to dhcp4: yes. In bash command line try 'netplan apply' and look into log 'journalctl'

Comment: still not working, what should i be looking for in journalctl?

Comment: after 'netplan apply' there should be something with dhcp in journalctl. Either an error or success. Are you sure there is a dhcp server running in your network segment? You can also try 'dhclient -v' and post your output here.

Comment: Instead of `ethernets:`  use `modems:` Read more: [Netplan Modems](https://netplan.io/reference/#properties-for-device-type-modems%3A)